# Using Yii active record to read multiple rows from DB

Tags: php, activerecord, model, yii

I would like to be able to read multiple rows using the Yii framework without having to create multiple model objects. With that In mind, I'm setting up a CDbCriteria with a condition of the form RowName = :param0 OR RowName = param1... RowName = ParamN and a corresponding params value.

My problems are two fold. The first is that the findall fails. The second is that I don't know how to get an error code out of the findall call (thus the return "heartBeat" line).

```
class Xactions extends CActiveRecord
{
.
.
.
//example $requests data: '192.168.1.162, 192.168.1.161'
//This function should return a Xactions model which is associated with any rows
// where tcpAddress = $requests Comma separated values.
public static function HeartBeatmodel($requests)
{
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $request_arr =  explode(',', $requests);
        $criteria->condition=Xactions::request_condition("tcpAddress", count($request_arr));;
        $criteria->params= Xactions::request_params($request_arr);
        $return= Xactions::model()->findall($criteria);
        return "heartBeat"; // here for debugging purposes
}
public static function request_condition($column_name, $num_request){
        //want to end up with name=:param1 OR name=:param2....
        $return_str = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_request; $i++){
            $return_str .= $column_name . '=param' . (string)$i . ' ';
            if($i == $num_request -1 ) break; //prevents extra OR statement
            $return_str .= 'OR ';
        }
        return $return_str;
}

public static function request_params($requests){
        $return_arr = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($requests); $i++){
            $return_arr['param' . (string)$i] = $requests[$i];
        }
        return $return_arr;
    }
```

Comment: it's spelled findAll? maybe that's the problem?

Comment: No, that wasn't the problem sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work?

```
class Xactions extends CActiveRecord {
        public static function HeartBeatmodel($requests) {
                $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
                $request_arr =  explode(',', $requests);

                for($request_arr as $request) {
                    $criteria->compare('tcpAddress', $request, false, 'OR');
                }

                return Xactions::model()->findAll($criteria);
        }
```

I'm using CDbCriteria->compare, you can find the specification here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail

As you can see, I set `$partialMatch` to false and the `$operator` to `OR` so it should accomplish what you want, right?

edit: I just realized, the smartest way to do this would be like this

```
public static function HeartBeatmodel($requests) {
  $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
  $criteria->addInCondition('tcpAddress', explode(',', $requests));

  return Xactions::model()->findAll($criteria);
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, I'll have to test this tomorrow and report back my findings.